# GPS device not detected by gpsctl

Tags: tty, hardware, serial-port, gpsd

My GPS device (/dev/ttyUSB2) outputs NMEA sentences when connected to with minicom or cat, but when using gpsctl with gpsd (running gpsd /dev/ttyUSB2) the following output is generated:
`gpsctl: no devices connected.`

I'm using `gpsd -ND5 /dev/ttyUSB2` which produces the following as output:

```
 
gpsd: successfully connected to the DBUS system bus
gpsd: running with effective group ID 0
gpsd: running with effective user ID 0
gpsd: opening GPS data source at '/dev/ttyUSB2'
gpsd: speed 9600, 8N1
gpsd: => GPS: $PASHQ,RID*28\x0d
```

gpsd: Navcom: command dump: 
gpsd: => GPS: 
gpsd: Navcom: sent command 0x1c (Test Support Block)
gpsd: Navcom: command 0x1c mode = 02, length = 0
gpsd: Navcom: command dump: 
gpsd: => GPS: 
gpsd: Navcom: sent command 0x20 (Data Request) - data block id = ae at rate 00
gpsd: Navcom: command dump: 
gpsd: => GPS: 
gpsd: Navcom: sent command 0x20 (Data Request) - data block id = 86 at rate 0a
gpsd: garmin_gps not active.
gpsd: no probe matched...
gpsd: gpsd_activate(0): opened GPS (5)

The serial device is producing NMEA sentences, but to me it seems that gpsd is unable to receive and decode them. Why could this be, and how do I solve it?

The GPS receiver in question is a Qualcomm Gobi 2000 inside my laptop, and operates normally at 9600 baud.

**Update:** When using -D8 to give extra debug info, I see that "gpsd: select waits" is shown repeatedly after the failed attempts to recognize the GPS device. The GPS does receive "GPS: $PASHQ,RID*28\x0d" but fails to parse this as a valid NMEA sentence.

Thanks.

Comment: Does gpscat -s 9600 /dev/ttyUSB2 show data?

Comment: @ctrl-d yes, that shows the NMEA data from the device.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? try gpsmon

Comment: (after starting gpsd)

Comment: @ctrl-d No, it's definitely not working. When I run gpspipe -w all I get is "GPSD,W=1" and no more output

Comment: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Talk:Qualcomm_Gobi_2000 Read this. Gobi 2000  looks flaky on linux;. Also, are you sure that you see correct NMEA sentences, with position info?

Comment: @ctrl-d I am issuing "$GPS_START" to the GPS serial port when it is required, and the output NMEA sentences do contain correct position information. I don't know what else I'm doing wrong, to me it seems it should be working.

Comment: I don't know, but i would then guess that gpsd tries to use a specific driver mode for that hardware instead of using plain NMEA. Maybe fiddle with gpsctl. Good luck.